# parse nested string with keys and sanitization - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, lexer

I have a string of data that I need to parse and sanitize for output in a human readable format. I'd like to use javascript to convert the string into a keyed array, retaining the nested hierarchy.

For example, I have this string:

```
(id, foo bar,category(subCategory,location(id)), something)
```

And I'd like to parse this and use maybe a keyed array to output this on a page like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>id<li>
    <li>foo bar</li>
    <li>category
        <ul>
            <li>subCategory<li>
            <li>location
                <ul>
                    <li>id</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>something</li>
</ul>
```

What is the most flexible way to achieve this using javascript, while also removing spaces in between values and the comma, but retaining that space between words?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: you can use the split method I guess, your solution should be kind of a recursion,  parsing text is not a trivial operation and one could not underestimate it.

Comment: What does this have to do with lexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` with regular expressions to acheive what you want. The replacements would be:

1. replace `/\(/g` (open parens) with `'<ul><li>'`. (`/\s*\(\s*/g` to remove surrounding spaces if any)
2. replace `/\)/g` (close parens) with `'</li></ul>'`. (`/\s*\)\s*/g` to remove surrounding spaces if any)
3. replace `/,/g` (commas) with `'</li><li>'`. (`/\s*,\s*/g` to remove surrounding spaces if any)

```js
var str = "(id, foo bar,category(subCategory,location(id)), something)";

str = str.replace(/\s*\(\s*/g, '<ul><li>')
         .replace(/\s*\)\s*/g, '</li></ul>')
         .replace(/\s*,\s*/g,  '</li><li>');

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```